# Displaying a Pop Up Message before standard Case Save Button

Tags: case

I have seen similar questions but no answers to this particular situation.
I want to show a Pop Up message when someone clicks on standard 'Save' button. 
This should be applicable to both situations
1) When user does Inline Edit and click Save.
2) When User clicks on Edit button and make changes and then click Save.
Please note i cannot use a Custom VF page. I want to achieve the above requirements with using Salesforce standard Layouts (both Detail and Edit )
Thanks in advance..
Chellappa

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done using the standard buttons and page layouts. You need to write a VF page to do this.

Someone on the developer forums had this same question bit more specifically asked about using a custom button a while ago. There answered question can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000097tMIAQ) which seems to suggest it is possible however this solution is prone to issues if Salesforce update their Javascript files or something during a release and alter the way the save system works for standard buttons (although this is highly unlikely).

My personal view would be that you should not need to display a pop-up on save (assumedly it is for confirmation?) as this is not a useful function to have in the system and you could simply turn on field history tracking to audit what changes have been made by people.

Comment: Ok i was expecting this. Can you tell if it is possible to hide the standard 'Save' button and provide Custom button. If Yes, can u also confirm if it works for Inline Edit save also.

Comment: I have added a link to a custom button based solution but as per the answer I would not recommend a pop-up on save and would suggest using field history tracking or something similar.

Comment: You should head pbattisson's advice. Do not use the javascript hack. I have had to rip out those hacks several times at clients during re-implementation projects due to poor work.

Comment: It looks like i have no choice,but to think of other options. While i was waiting for some responses, i had a discussion with Business. They were fine with having a separate button , along with Save. So all the extra logic which i wanted on Save , we can do it with new custom button. My requirement was to trigger some validations before making a webservice call to Oracle. With the new custom button, i can perform those validations. Thanks for the responses again.